# Center div inside header

Tags: css, html

I am trying to center the logo for my last media query targeting screens below 479px. I am having trouble. Every time I have margin auto, the browser pushes the img to the right. This is what I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/Bliss_FinalLogo_2.png" alt="Logo" />
        </div>
    </header>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px){

    li.main_nav {
        float:none;
        width:100%;
    }

    .learn_info {
        width:100%;
    }

    nav {
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: none;
        border:none;
    }

    #logo{
        display: block;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }

    a{
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a width for `#logo`. If you don't want to do that then you can set `text-align:center` for `header`.

http://jsfiddle.net/6kWfU/